# what is the best way to handle ALL jquery ajax errors at once?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery Ajax script like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// $('.do-something').click(function (e) {
$(document).on('click','#do-something',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?id=" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        if(json.valid == 1) {

            $("#hidden-div").show();

        }
        else {

            $("#hidden-error-div").show();

        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

       $("#hidden-error-div").show(); 

    },
    timeout: 15000
  });
});
});
```

But I have a feeling that I'm not handling all the potential errors correctly. Is there a way to handle ALL the errors that may happen at once in the `error` function, including timeout?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has a nice global error handler [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxerror/) which you can turn off locally, with property `global` set to `false`, any request not having `global` set to `false` will trigger the callback you previously set.

As for the timeout you can use [`.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to set it globally.
There is one thing that might block, it's the part inside the success where you check for errors, but you could be able to isolate the check, and the error callback, so that ajaxError and success call the same function if something failed.

Your code could look something like this

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   timeout: 15000
});

$(document).ajaxError(function () {
    $("#hidden-error-div").show();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
// $('.do-something').click(function (e) {
$(document).on('click','#do-something',function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.domain.com/page.php?id=" + id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
        if(json.valid == 1) {

            $("#hidden-div").show();

        }
        else {

            $("#hidden-error-div").show();

        }
    }
  });
});
});
```